# React app with multiple pages for different data sets

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on building out a frontend app that will handle different api calls. Each call is making a request for different data and there will be 10-12 data sets being pulled in. I'm trying to create an app that will feature the different data sets on the home page and when the user clicks one, they will be navigated to a detail page where they can view a table.

What's the best approach for this? In the past working with React I've only had to work with one data set. But for this each page will show different data. Do I need to just create 10 different pages, since data will be different for each page or is there a better approach for this?

Comment: If you want to create a web app in React, NextJS is a safe bet (https://nextjs.org/).

Comment: @JonathanDsouza why? Unless OP needs SSR there's no reason to use an opinionated framework like Next.js. Not that I'm against Next (on the contrary) but client side rendered apps are fine to use for logged in apps such as admin panels and other non-indexed apps. Not to mention OP might not want to run Node on the server and use a different backend.

Comment: @Undo. Opinionated frameworks are not a bad thing. It gives you a definitive starting point, solves many problems right out of the box, and makes your project more future-proof. The current industry trend is to use meta frameworks like Next & Remix. 

Having said that I broadly agree with you. It depends on the context, If you are comfortable working with React and the React ecosystem I highly recommend (React + Vite). RIP CRA.